# DotNetZip extracting files (empty but still filename) if password wrong

Tags: c#, zip, 7zip, dotnetzip

I am using dotnetzip and using the AES encryption option.
When extracting if I enter the correct password everything works great.
However if I enter a wrong password then it tells me its the wrong password but it still extracts the folder and shows all the file names etc although they are not decrypted as they are 0 bytes and empty.

What I want to do is if the password is wrong then nothing should happen,
Now I know that it is the program that I am using for extracting that is finding the filenames so does dotnetzip have a way to hide the file names unless the zip is decrypted first?

Comment: What if the password is correct but the archive is corrupted? Do you expect it to only create files it fully succeeded before the fault, or none at all? Even if you can't get around to change the implementation to suit your needs, why not just delete the files upon failure?

Comment: Because the zipped files can be unzipped by other programs, this program is just zipping them up and encrypting them